# Is there any way on Azure to get the metadata of different file types?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to get metadata of different file types ( .xml , .mov , .mp3 , .mp4 , .jpeg , .png etc ). Is there any way in Azure data factory to do so? it's unclear how to set a get metadata task data set without specifying the file type (More specifically unstructured data).

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to specify the file type to get its metadata. Please have a look at [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6246/azure-data-factory-get-metadata-example/) that explains step by step how you can do it. Note: The source type is different from the file type. So, the solution in the article is dependent on the source type, but in your case is file-based source.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful. I was able to get most of the metadata by using this. I came across with one more parameter in the requirements though. How do I fetch "Created By"? (like Who created the file). I dont see any default options to do so in Get Metadata activity.

Comment: In the article I made reference, the property "Created By" is not available. So, out of the box you are not able to access that information. Please access the Data Factory feedback forum, and suggest the feature so they can make it available. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory. Please be aware that using the Created By or Modified By can have some implications in terms of GDPR. So you should assess if you really need to use that information...